# Google maps tile entire world with Maptiler

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I'm completely new to map titling etc. I'm trying to tile the entire world map starting form zoom level 3 using Maptiler (http://www.maptiler.org).

Now my problems are: first, not sure how the image should be. I took a screengrab of the world map at zoom level 3 and drawn my map on top of it following the outline for each country. Is it how you do it?
Also in Maptiler when asked for the Georeference bounding box, it's by default 90 -90 180 -180. Is this the bounding box for the entire world?
Leaving the next step settings as default, meaning the SRS as "WGS84 Latitude and Longitude (geodetic)" (I don't really know how to use those settings, shouldn't I use the Mercator one for Google map? I'm confused...) and setting in the following step the zoom from 3 (my minimum zoom level) to 5, the final overlay on Google map results distorted being squashed towards the equator and stretched over the poles, also there are gaps around the "worlds" left, right, top and bottom, as you can see from the image.

Any advice and/or tips?

Thanks

[image: My map tiled with Maptiler]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved. Just needed to use [this image](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File%3aUtm-zones.jpg) as reference and leave all the settings as default

Answer (score 0):

Google Maps uses a z-curve to reduce the dimension complexity and reorder the tiles. It also add some spatial information to the reorder. Read about it here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb259689.aspx. Hence you need a projection (mercantor) from lat-lng pair to x,y pair and from x,y pair to quad-key (z-curve).